# stacked bar and line chart in same graph with any android library?

Tags: android, achartengine, androidplot, mpandroidchart

Its been almost two days m struggling to use compound graph with following features:-

1. graph with stacked bar and line chart together.
2. Two y-axis (one at right and other at left) with differnt data set.
3. Tooltip that display current touched coordinates of graph.

I had tried following android graph libraries:-

1. **MPAndroidchart**

   This library doesnt supports compound graphs. But i love this library, since rest features are up to the mark.(wish this would had supported Compond graphs.)
2. **AndroidPlot**

   It does support Compound graph but no tooltip and multiple y-axis.
3. **AchartEngine**

   Supports compound graphs. Look and feel is not that good. No tooltip support. Support Heap bar(stacked) but you cannot use this along with any other chart type in same graph.

So, is there any other library that can match my requirement ?
or 
how could i implement this using libraries that i mentioned.

Comment: did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: yeah buddy!!... Your suggestion saved me n my time :) ..thnx a lot..
Hellocharts do support Stacked bar and line chart in same graph(ComboLineColumnChartView)..
Also supports different Y-Axis(right ,Left)...X-axis(Top and Bottom)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/) can do all of this. The demo app shows a "Combo Line/Column Chart" to satisfy point 1 and a "Speed Chart" to satisfy requirement 2. Point 3 works in all their charts from what I can tell.

The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is if the ComboLineColumnChartView also supports two Y-axis like the LineChartView, but I don't see why not. Let me know if it works.